# Getting Error - expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token

Tags: c++, binary-search

```
#include using namespace std; int hhc(int a[],int n,int k) { int e=0; int v=n-1; while(e<=v) { int g=(e+v)/2; if(a[g]==k) { return(g); } else if(a[g]>k) { e=g+1;
}

else { v=g-1; } return(-1); } } int main() { int n; cin>>n; int a[n]; int i; for(i=0;i<n;i++) { cin>>a[i]; } int k; cin>>k; int d= hhc(a[],n,k); cout<<d<<endl; return(0); }
```

Comment: `#include` is a preprocessor directive that expects a filename. The way you're using it indicates you don't have much experience with C++. Are you taking a class? Can you consult your teaching staff?

Answer (score 0):

Since the C++ complier needs the array size at compile time, it is giving that error. Instead we can use vector, which is dynamic in nature and solve the problem. I have updated the code and it is compiling fine. Hope this will solve your problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std; 
int hhc(vector<int> a, int n, int k)
{
    int e = 0;
    int v = n - 1;
    while (e <= v) {
        int g = (e + v) / 2;
        if (a[g] == k) {
            return(g);
        }
        else if (a[g] > k) {
            e = g + 1;
        }

        else {
            v = g - 1;
        }
        return(-1);
    }
}
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    //int a[n];
    vector<int> a(n, 0);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    int d = hhc(a, n, k);
    cout << d << endl;
    return(0);
}
```